# Node.js request module form data key

Tags: node.js, forms, request

I need to do a post with node request module with form data.
Form data keys are dynamic. It is from a variable. How to place that in the code below? I want to substitute k1 and v1 in place of field1 and "data".

```
var request = require('request');
var k1 = "mykey";
var v1 = "myval";
request.post({
    header: {"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    url: 'https://modulus.io/contact/demo',
    form: {
        field1: "data"
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
});
```

if i place like below in the above code , it works:

```
form: {
    "mykey": "myval"
}
```

but if i give it like below, it fails:

```
form: {
    k1: v1
}
```

when i read it comes as

```
k1="myval";
```

Tried like,

```
form: {
    ""+k1: v1
}
```

system says, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token +"
not sure how to get

```
mykey = "myval";
```

Please light me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the following syntax

```
form[k1] = v1
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who didnt get the previous answer, like me:

```
var request = require('request');
var k1 = "mykey";
var v1 = "myval";   
request.post({
   header: {"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
   url: 'https://modulus.io/contact/demo',
   form: {
      [k1]:v1
   }
 }, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(response.statusCode, body);
});
```